# AMAZON SES: Sending email to users in HTML format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I want to change my current text email format to HTML format, so that I can send an email in nicely formatted way with headers, font values etc as shown in the screenshot below.
[Image showing email body with header font size etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkCug.png)

Currently I have text format for sending email using AWS.ses

```
exports.sendEmail = function(email, token, event, context) {
var  ses = new AWS.SES({
  region: process.env.SES_REGION
});
var eParams = {
    Destination: {
        ToAddresses: [email]
    },
    Message: {
        Body: {
            Text: {
              //template or environment variable
              Data: `Hello ${event.request.userAttributes.given_name},\n\nYour Device Validation Token is ${token}\nSimply copy this token and paste it into the device validation input field.`
            }
        },
        Subject: {
          //template or environment variable
            Data: "CWDS - CARES Device Validation Token"
        }
    },
    //environment variable
    Source: process.env.SOURCE_EMAIL
};

/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
ses.sendEmail(eParams, function(err, data){
  if(err) {
    logWrapper.logExceptOnTest("FAILURE SENDING EMAIL - Device Verify OTP");
    logWrapper.logExceptOnTest(event);
    logWrapper.logExceptOnTest(context);
    context.fail(err);
  }
  else {
    logWrapper.logExceptOnTest("Device Verify OTP sent");
    context.succeed(event);
  }
});
/* eslint-enable no-unused-vars */
```

}

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's fairly straight forward, just add the Html section of the Body node, i.e.:

```
var eParams = {
    Destination: {
        ToAddresses: [email]
    },
    Message: {
        Body: {
            Text: {
                Data: `Hello ${event.request.userAttributes.given_name},\n\nYour Device Validation Token is ${token}\nSimply copy this token and paste it into the device validation input field.`
            },
            Html: {
                Data: `<html><head><title>Your Token</title><style>h1{color:#f00;}</style></head><body><h1>Hello ${event.request.userAttributes.given_name},</h1><div>Your Device Validation Token is ${token}<br/>Simply copy this token and paste it into the device validation input field.</div></body></html>`
            }
        },
        Subject: {
            //template or environment variable
            Data: "CWDS - CARES Device Validation Token"
        }
    },
    //environment variable
    Source: process.env.SOURCE_EMAIL
};
```

---

*However...* I generally split out the email template into html and text files, and use handlebars to inject data items. Here is an extract of one of my working solutions:

**contact/contact.js**

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var ses = new AWS.SES();
var fs = require('fs');
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');
    
module.exports.sendemail = (event, context, callback) =>
   var eventData = JSON.parse(event.body);
    
   fs.readFile("./contact/emailtemplate.html", function (err, emailHtmlTemplate) {
       if (err) {
           console.log("Unable to load HTML Template");
           throw err;
       }
       fs.readFile("./contact/emailtemplate.txt", function (err, emailTextTemplate) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Unable to load TEXT Template");
                throw err;
            }

            // Prepare data for template placeholders
            var emailData = {
                "given_name": event.request.userAttributes.given_name,
                "token": token
            };
    
            // Inject data into templates
            var templateTitle = Handlebars.compile(process.env.EMAIL_TITLE);
            var titleText = templateTitle(emailData);
            console.log(titleText);
    
            emailData.title = titleText;
    
            var templateText = Handlebars.compile(emailTextTemplate.toString());
            var bodyText = templateText(emailData);
            console.log(bodyText);

            var templateHtml = Handlebars.compile(emailHtmlTemplate.toString());
            var bodyHtml = templateHtml(emailData);
            console.log(bodyHtml);
    
            // Prepare SES params
            
            var params = {
                Destination: {
                    ToAddresses: [
                        process.env.EMAIL_TO
                    ]
                },
                Message: {
                    Body: {
                        Text: {
                            Data: bodyText,
                            Charset: 'UTF-8'
                        },
                        Html: {
                            Data: bodyHtml
                        },
                    },
                    Subject: {
                        Data: titleText,
                        Charset: 'UTF-8'
                    }
                },
                Source: process.env.EMAIL_FROM
            }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(params,null,4));
            
            // Send Email
            
            ses.sendEmail(params, function(err,data){
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err,err.stack); // error
                    var response = {
                        statusCode: 500,
                        headers: {
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({"message":"Error: Unable to Send Message"})
                    }
                    callback(null, response);
                }
                else  {
                    console.log(data); // success
    
                    var response = {
                        statusCode: 200,
                        headers: {
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({"message":"Message Sent"})
                    }
                    callback(null, response);
                }
            });
   
         }); //end of load text template
    }); //end of load html template
};
```

**contact/emailtemplate.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your New Token</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style>
        h1 { color:#f00; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="emailwrapper">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Hi {{given_name}}</h1>
            <div style="padding:20px;">
                <div>your new token is {{token}}.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**contact/emailtemplate.txt**

```
Hi {{given_name}}

your new token is {{token}}.
```

---

### UPDATE 2023 (ES6 + AWS-SDK)

Here is the ES6 version using the newer AWS SDK, and some other optimisations:

```
import { SESClient, SendEmailCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-ses';
import fs from 'fs/promises';
import Handlebars from 'handlebars';
import util from 'util';

const ses = new SESClient({ region: 'your-aws-region' }); // Replace 'your-aws-region' with the appropriate AWS region

const readFileAsync = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

export const sendemail = async (event, context, callback) => {
    try {
        const eventData = JSON.parse(event.body);
        const [emailHtmlTemplate, emailTextTemplate] = await Promise.all([
            readFileAsync("./contact/emailtemplate.html"),
            readFileAsync("./contact/emailtemplate.txt")
        ]);

        // Prepare data for template placeholders
        const emailData = {
            "given_name": event.request.userAttributes.given_name,
            "token": token // Where does 'token' come from? You need to define it.
        };

        // Inject data into templates
        const templateTitle = Handlebars.compile(process.env.EMAIL_TITLE);
        const titleText = templateTitle(emailData);
        console.log(titleText);

        emailData.title = titleText;

        const templateText = Handlebars.compile(emailTextTemplate.toString());
        const bodyText = templateText(emailData);
        console.log(bodyText);

        const templateHtml = Handlebars.compile(emailHtmlTemplate.toString());
        const bodyHtml = templateHtml(emailData);
        console.log(bodyHtml);

        // Prepare SES params
        const params = {
            Destination: {
                ToAddresses: [process.env.EMAIL_TO]
            },
            Message: {
                Body: {
                    Text: {
                        Data: bodyText,
                        Charset: 'UTF-8'
                    },
                    Html: {
                        Data: bodyHtml
                    },
                },
                Subject: {
                    Data: titleText,
                    Charset: 'UTF-8'
                }
            },
            Source: process.env.EMAIL_FROM
        };
        console.log(JSON.stringify(params, null, 4));

        // Send Email
        const sendEmailCommand = new SendEmailCommand(params);
        await ses.send(sendEmailCommand);

        const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ "message": "Message Sent" })
        };
        callback(null, response);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error, error.stack); // error
        const response = {
            statusCode: 500,
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ "message": "Error: Unable to Send Message" })
        };
        callback(null, response);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you @Matt D for the help. Adding html directly to the body worked.
But I have few questions when split out the email template into html and text files.
1. Where is the file name in this line? ```fs.readFile('./contact/' + process.env.EMAIL_TEMPLATE + ".html", function (err, emailHtmlTemplate) {```

Comment: In my example it's passed in as an environment variable, so I can reuse the code for any email template requirement. `'./contact/' + process.env.EMAIL_TEMPLATE + '.html'` that could be replaced by `mytemplate.html` sorry for over complicating it.

Comment: Yes. Thank you @Matt D

Comment: Sorry I am new to stack over flow, How to accept answer?

Comment: Hey @matt D can you please have a look at one of other question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335925/giving-user-capability-of-resetting-expired-temporary-password-in-cognito

Comment: So @Matt D, to clarify you don't utilise the SES "template" storage ability at all? Instead you just use the "sendEmail" endpoint and fill/provide your own template?